# Calculadora não detecta numeros com dois dígitos

Tags: c#

Eu estou a fazer uma calculadora em c#, mas calculadora, não sei porque, não deteta números com 2 dígitos, como por exemplo 11+1 = 3, a calculadora está a detetar como se estivesse 1 + 1 + 1. Segue o código:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Hello_World
{
    public partial class Calculadora : Form
    {
        public Calculadora()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        #region "Strings Doubles Bools"
        double total1 = 0;
        double total2 = 0;
        double total3 = 0;
        string theOperator = "";
        bool plusButtonClicked = false;
        bool minusButtonClicked = false;
        bool divideButtonClicked = false;
        bool multiplyButtonClicked = false;
#endregion

        #region "Função btn"
        //Função do btn de 0
        private void btn0_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextDisplay.Text = TextDisplay.Text + btn0.Text;
        }

        //Função do btn de 1
        private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextDisplay.Text = TextDisplay.Text + btn1.Text;
        }

        //Função do btn de 2
        private void btn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextDisplay.Text = TextDisplay.Text + btn2.Text;
        }

        //Função do btn de 3
        private void btn3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextDisplay.Text = TextDisplay.Text + btn3.Text;
        }

        //Função do btn de 4
        private void btn4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextDisplay.Text = TextDisplay.Text + btn4.Text;
        }

        //Função do btn de 5
        private void btn5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextDisplay.Text = TextDisplay.Text + btn5.Text;
        }

        //Função do btn de 6
        private void btn6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextDisplay.Text = TextDisplay.Text + btn6.Text;
        }

        //Função do btn de 7
        private void btn7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextDisplay.Text = TextDisplay.Text + btn7.Text;
        }

        //Função do btn de 8
        private void btn8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextDisplay.Text = TextDisplay.Text + btn8.Text;
        }

        //Função do btn de 9
        private void btn9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextDisplay.Text = TextDisplay.Text + btn9.Text;
        }

        //Função do btn de Equal
        private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Clear();
        }


        //Função do btn de Plus
        private void btnplus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Plus();
        }

        //Função do btn de Equal
        private void btnequal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Equal();
        }

        //Função do btn de Less
        private void btnless_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Less();
        }

        //Função do btn de Divisão
        private void btnDivisçao_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Divisão();
        }

        //Função do btn de Multiplicação
        private void bntMulti_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Multi();
        }

        //Função do btn virugla
        private void btnVirgula_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextDisplay.Text = TextDisplay.Text + btnVirgula.Text;
        }

        //Quando a calculadora carregar
        private void Calculadora_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextDisplay.Focus();
        }
#endregion

        #region "Public Voids"
        //Função Equal
        public void Equal()
        {
            switch (theOperator)
            {
                case "+":
                    total2 = total1 + double.Parse(total3.ToString());
                    break;
                case "-":
                    total2 = total1 - double.Parse(total3.ToString());
                    break;
                case "/":
                    total2 = total1 / double.Parse(total3.ToString());
                    break;
                case "*":
                    total2 = total1 * double.Parse(total3.ToString());
                    break;
                default:
                    MessageBox.Show("Este simbolo não é reconhecido", "Erro", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    break;
            }
            TextDisplay.Text = TextDisplay.Text + "\r\n" + total2.ToString();
            total1 = 0;
        }

        //Função Plus
        public void Plus()
        {

            if (total3 != 0)
            {
                total1 = total1 + total3;
                total3 = 0;
            }
            //else
            //    total1 = total1 + double.Parse(TextDisplay.Text);


            TextDisplay.Text = TextDisplay.Text + " + ";

            plusButtonClicked = true;
            minusButtonClicked = false;
            divideButtonClicked = false;
            multiplyButtonClicked = false;
            theOperator = "+";
        }

        //Função Multi
        public void Multi()
        {
            if (total3 != 0)
            {
                total1 = total1 * total3;
                total3 = 0;
            }
            TextDisplay.Text = TextDisplay.Text + " * ";

            plusButtonClicked = false;
            minusButtonClicked = false;
            divideButtonClicked = false;
            multiplyButtonClicked = true;
            theOperator = "*";
        }

        //Função Divisão
        public void Divisão()
        {
            total1 = total1 + double.Parse(TextDisplay.Text);
            TextDisplay.Text = TextDisplay.Text + " / ";

            plusButtonClicked = false;
            minusButtonClicked = false;
            divideButtonClicked = true;
            multiplyButtonClicked = false;
            theOperator = "/";
        }

        //Função Less
        public void Less()
        {
            total1 = total1 + double.Parse(TextDisplay.Text);
            TextDisplay.Text = TextDisplay.Text + " - ";

            plusButtonClicked = false;
            minusButtonClicked = true;
            divideButtonClicked = false;
            multiplyButtonClicked = false;
            theOperator = "-";
        }

        //Função Clear
        public void Clear()
        {
            TextDisplay.Clear();

        }

        //Funcção de deteção de presionamento de teclas
        public void Detect(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar == 48 || e.KeyChar == 49 || e.KeyChar == 50 || e.KeyChar == 51 || e.KeyChar == 52 || e.KeyChar == 53 || e.KeyChar == 54 || e.KeyChar == 55 || e.KeyChar == 56 || e.KeyChar == 57 || e.KeyChar == 58)
            {
                TextDisplay.Text = TextDisplay.Text + e.KeyChar.ToString();

                if(total1 != 0)
                    total3 = Convert.ToDouble(e.KeyChar.ToString());
                else
                    total1 = total1 + double.Parse(TextDisplay.Text);
                if (total1 != 0)
                { 

                }
                }

            //Detetor da tecla Equal
            if (e.KeyChar == 61)
            {

                Equal();
            }

            //Detetor da tecla Multi
            if (e.KeyChar == 42)
            {
                Multi();
            }

            //Detetor da tecla Plus
            if (e.KeyChar == 43)
            {
                total1 = Convert.ToDouble(TextDisplay.Text);
                Plus();
            }

            //Detetor da tecla Divisão
            if (e.KeyChar == 47)
            {
                Divisão();
            }

            //Detetor da tecla  less
            if (e.KeyChar == 45)
            {
                Less();
            }

            //DetetoR da tecla backspace
            if (e.KeyChar == 8)
            {
                if (TextDisplay.Text == "")
                {
                    System.Media.SystemSounds.Beep.Play();
                }
                else
                {
                    if (TextDisplay.Text.Length == 1)
                    {
                        TextDisplay.Text = "";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        TextDisplay.Text = TextDisplay.Text.Substring(0, TextDisplay.Text.Length - 1);
                    }
                }
            }

            //Detetor da tecla enter
            if (e.KeyChar == 13)
            {
                Equal();
            }

            //Detetor da tecla Esc
            if (e.KeyChar == 27)
            {

                Clear();
            }

            //Detetor da tecla virgula ou ponto
            if (e.KeyChar == 46 || e.KeyChar == 44)
            {
                TextDisplay.Text = TextDisplay.Text + e.KeyChar.ToString();
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region "Deteção de teclas"
        //Deteção de presionamento de teclas text Display
        private void TextDisplay_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            Detect(sender, e);
        }
        #region "Numeros de 0 a 9"
        //Detecão de presionamento de teclas no btn 0
        private void btn0_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            Detect(sender, e);
        }

        //Detecão de presionamento de teclas no btn 1
        private void btn1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            Detect(sender, e);
        }

        //Detecão de presionamento de teclas no btn 2
        private void btn2_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            Detect(sender, e);
        }

        //Detecão de presionamento de teclas no btn 3
        private void btn3_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            Detect(sender, e);
        }

        //Detecão de presionamento de teclas no btn 4
        private void btn4_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            Detect(sender, e);
        }

        //Detecão de presionamento de teclas no btn 5
        private void btn5_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            Detect(sender, e);
        }

        //Detecão de presionamento de teclas no btn 6
        private void btn6_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            Detect(sender, e);
        }

        //Detecão de presionamento de teclas no btn 7
        private void btn7_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            Detect(sender, e);
        }

        //Detecão de presionamento de teclas no btn 8
        private void btn8_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            Detect(sender, e);
        }

        //Detecão de presionamento de teclas no btn 9
        private void btn9_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            Detect(sender, e);
        }
        #endregion

        #region "Btns de Operações"
        //Deteção de percinamento da tecla +
        private void btnplus_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            Detect(sender, e);
        }

        //Deteção de percinamento da tecla -
        private void btnless_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            Detect(sender, e);
        }

        //Deteção de percinamento da tecla /
        private void btnDivisçao_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            Detect(sender, e);
        }

        //Deteção de percinamento da tecla *
        private void bntMulti_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            Detect(sender, e);
        }

        //Deteção de percinamento da tecla =
        private void btnequal_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            Detect(sender, e);
        }

        //Deteção de percinamento da tecla esc
        private void btnClear_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            Detect(sender, e);
        }

        //Deteção de percionamento da tecla ,
        private void btnVirgula_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            Detect(sender, e);
        }
        #endregion
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Enquanto o tempo passava e eu tentava resolver o meu codigo consegui resolver o problema de 11 + 1 = 3 agora falta a segunda parte do problema que é 11 + 11 = 13

Comment: Não entendi seu problema, e de casas decimais ou de soma de valores? outra onde isso esta acontecendo exatamente em seu código?

Comment: @MarconcílioSouza não tenho bem acertesa porque não é um erro mas sim um bug o prolema e que se eu fizer a conta por exemplo 11+11 vai dar 13 é como se estivesse 11 +1 +1

Comment: Então o que você pode fazer é debugar seu projeto e ver o que esta sendo feito com os valores de suas variáveis. Tem coisas como `total1 = total1 + total3;` que não sei para que você somar o valor de total1  novamente se o valor inicial é 0.

Comment: o valor de total 1 é mudado quando eu clicar + espera um pouco vou dar um update no codigo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amigo, francamente acho que a abordagem está errada do seu software. Creio que deverias considerar para o desenvolvimento de qualquer software a informatização do processo, e para isso, replicar via software o que fazemos no processo real.

Sua lógica não replica o processo real de uma operação matemática dando margem para bugs, logo analisemos o processo primeiro:

Quando realizamos qualquer operação matemática (via calculadora física ou na papel) o que fazemos:

1. Escolhemos o primeiro número
2. Escolhemos a operação
3. Escolhemos o segundo número
4. Calculamos a operação pois já temos todos os dados necessários!

Este é o processo! Seu software não pode fugir disso... ou seja.. ele precisa armazenar um número, uma operação e o segundo número!

Vejo que está no caminho certo com pequenas falhas...

Sugestões de melhoria:

1. Armazene o primeiro número em uma variável double chamada **Numero1**
2. Armazene a operação como uma **ENUM**, assim fica mais seguro o seu código.
3. Aramzene o segundo número em uma variável double chamada **Numero2**
4. Deixe **apenas** a variável de Total com o nome Total
5. Retire todas as operações de dentro dos métodos do operadores, deixe apenas no igual!

Acho que seguindo estes passos irá resolver o teu problema!

Comment: Podeme dizer oque é um enum?

Comment: Enum é uma enumeração, que garante que somente aqueles tipos (baseados em valor) poderão ser aceitos, é algo bem simples, por exemplo: 
`enum Operacoes
{
     Somar,
     Subtrair,
     Dividir,
     Multiplicar
}`

Quando fizer o switch, verás q é bem melhor! Basta colocar a variável do tipo desta Enum que o visual studio monta todo o switch para você (teclando TAB)!

Por exemplo, aí você cria uma variável do tipo desta enum:

`Operacoes Operador;`

Para setá-la:

`Operador = Operacoes.Multiplicar;`

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda neste momento estou a fazer o codigo todo de novo o antigo esta guardado

Comment: Legal @pekira! Boa sorte e que esta pequena ajuda possa lhe conduzir sempre em um melhor processo de análise!

Comment: Eu gostaria de saber se me podia ajudar com mais uma coisa como é que eu faço para quando eu clicar num butão a double numero1 adicionar mais um numero no centido de quando eu clico num butão a double numero1 adiciona o numero 1 no sentido fe faz isto clico 1 fica 1 clico 2 fica 12 clico 0 fica 120

Comment: @pekira Consegue colocar uma imagem do Form na pergunta ?

Comment: como adiciono uma img a pergunta

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43417/discussion-between-mauricio-junior-and-pekira).

Comment: como é que eu faço isso

Comment: ja estou na sala